# Highlight the word under cursor in gvim

Tags: vim, highlight

How to highlight the word under cursor in vim.
Currently I do this by getting the word under cursor and then pressing `*`.
Sure, this does highlight the text, but the cursor moves to the next found word in the file (if the word exists more than once). But, I want the cursor to stay on the same word, while highlighting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added this function, it allows you to toggle highlighting of max 6 words in different colors by pressing `<leader> 1-6`, `<leader> -0` will clear all highlighting.

https://github.com/sk1418/myConf/blob/master/common/.vimrc#L729

the original idea was from sjl.

Comment: How do I add a function to vim? I am sorry, I am new to vim.

Comment: @SagarJain you could do what I did, add the function into your vimrc file.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have `hlsearch` on --which given your description of the <kbd>*</kbd> command I'm pretty sure you do-- you can create a mapping that sets the search register:

```
nnoremap <leader>* :<C-u>let @/ = expand('<cword>')<cr>
```

After using your mapping you can then jump to the next/previous result with <kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> like any other search.

Edit:

Since you asked me to describe what the mapping is doing I'll break it down.

- `nnoremap` says to create a non-recursive mapping.
- `<leader>*` is the key sequence for the mapping. By default `<leader>` is <kbd>\</kbd> so the actual mapping is <kbd>\</kbd> followed by <kbd>*</kbd>.  You can change this to be whatever you want, I just used it as an example.
- `:<C-u>` is probably not useful in this case but I found it was a good habit.  What it does is guarantees there is no range added to the command you are about to run.
- `let @/ =` is setting the `/` (search) register. This is where the last searched string is stored when you do a normal search.  We are manipulating this with our mapping to take advantage of the built in `hlsearch` and <kbd>n</kbd>/<kbd>N</kbd> features.
- `expand('<cword>')` is grabbing the word under the cursor.
- `<cr>` is just simulating you pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to actually finish the command.

Comment: I didn't understand the mapping. I'm quite new to vim. Could you please explain?

Comment: It's not working. I'm not sure I've mapped it right.
I just typed this and pressed enter

nnoremap /* :<C-u>let @/ = expand('<cword>')

Comment: Copy and paste it exactly as it is written.  The strings in `<>`s are interpreted by vim, they are not placeholders.

Comment: Ok. I did that. And then I pressed * to highlight the word under cursor. But, the cursor moved to next found word.

Comment: `"By default <leader> is /"` -- I think you meant \ (backslash)

Comment: @mMontu, oh my, I do indeed.  Fixed.

Comment: @SagarJain this command maps `<leader>*` to this command, not just plain `*`.  Press `\*` while over the word.  If you want to change the default behavior of `*` then remove the `<leader>` part from the mapping (although I don't recommend this!).

Comment: @RandyMorris, When I did \\* I see this 

:let @/ = expand ('<cword>')

Comment: That's correct. The word should have also been highlighted. If not, check that you have 'hlsearch' enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the [Mark plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2666), as it allows highlighting several words in different colors simultaneously. It is very stable, well documented, and easy to use.

It is possible to select a word to highlight directly or through regular expressions, and the plugin offer some mechanism to jump between occurrences of the marked word/expression.

Comment: Great! I think it's just what I wanted. Currently, net admin in my office prevents me from downloading that plugin. I'll try the plugin once I get the permission to download. Thanks!

Comment: Where's the plugin in that link to download?
I clicked on the download (on the left in green), but it looks like vim executable.

Comment: If you scroll down you will see the list of versions with the link to the package (*.vmb.gz) - the latest is 2.8.5. You can also [clone the repo in the github](https://github.com/zeroflyfire/Mark--Karkat).

Answer (score 0):

I did this in .vimrc which use F3 to highlight the word under cursor:

`nmap <F3> /<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>N`

the 'N' will return to the last position

Comment: This is basically RandyMorris's answer above. Infinite number of remappings possible to solve this problem.